# Simple shared menu on WIKI (2013)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, navigation, enterprise-wiki

I am having trouble understanding why the WIKI menu options are so bad in sharepoint, either that or I am doing it wrong. Likely the later.

Ive tried a few methods ive goolged and im not happy with any of them. ive resorted to creating a horizontal nav bar on the top of each page like so

```
MENU | [[Home]] | [[Comms]] | [[Sysadmin]] | [[Support]
```

I am happy with this, but the pain is if i ever want to make changes i need to change all my wiki pages (currently only 10) but its still a pain.

How can i use a webpart or anything to put the above menu on all my wiki pages and only edit 1 menu?

Thanks